# Procfile on Node.js/Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am rereading this tutorial
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction
to polish my understanding of `Node.js/Heroku`.

There is a section called *Define a Procfile*.

But when I go to see my own apps to check what is inside this file.
I see that a number of apps (not all) have no such a file and are working fine.

So, what is going on? When is `Procfile` necessary? What happens if there is none?
When is it better to have one?

Answer (score 1):

To help you get started, Heroku will try to automatically detect the type of your app and start it appropriately, even when it doesn't have a Profile (see example here - http://blog.taylorrf.com/blog/2014/12/15/heroku-default-server/ ).

For example in Node, if you have an `index.js` file and a `package.json` file, it's probably a node app that could be started with `node index.js`.

While convenient, this is considered bad practice, because:

1. Heroku may change how they auto detect apps in the future, breaking your deployment.
2. You might be missing out on some configurations / optimizations by doing so (see article linked above).